# 2D from 3D points in HALCON

Tags: halcon

Given a 3D point coordinate, the internal and the external camera parameters in a calibrated stereo camera setup, is there a HALCON method that gives me the 2D pixel coordinates on each camera?

Regards,
MSK

Answer (score 1):

You can project the coordinates into 2D world, if the camera parameters are known, using the following:

```
* Project 3D points into image.
project_3d_point(X, Y, Z, CameraParam, Row, Column)
```

Please refer to description [here](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/project_3d_point.html)

Comment: @Philip why was my link-fix edit rejected and the same link-fix subsequently applied?

Comment: @MattM because I find the name "Project 3D Point (HALCON docs)" redundant, which was also missing from the original response